# Firebase Realtime Database detailed usage

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Where can I get Firebase Realtime Database detailed usage i.e. I want to get details about where data is being used? My database size is about 700kb and 10GB downloaded in 2 days, I am unable to figure it out, how did this happen. Currently, the usage tab just showing me the basic usage by day. Can I get more detailed usage information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Firebase documentation on [monitoring usage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/monitor-usage), which lists two main options:

- The Usage in the Firebase console, which you already found.
- StackDriver monitoring, which will you give you more granular usage data.

If neither of these allow you to determine where the usage is coming from, you have a few more options/things to consider:

- Keep in mind that traffic for showing the database in the Firebase console is also charged. Especially early on in development this can be a major portion of the usage, as you won't have many users yet.
- You can use the [database profiler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile), which logs all the activity in your database over a given period of time.

Comment: Would help to see your database structure and know the number of users accessing it and how often they need to refresh their data. Basically, the usage model.